# how to connect 2 monitors in macbook pro 2020

Tags: macbook-pro, display, thunderbolt, apple-silicon

I have a Macbook Pro 2020 whose configurations are like follows:

> Apple M1 chip with 8-core CPU, 8-core GPU, and 16-core Neural Engine
> ..., ...
> Two Thunderbolt

And I have searched it before [which](https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/mchl7c7ebe08/mac) says I could connect to multiple monitors if used multiple adapters that support Thunderbolt.
But it does not work when I use 2 UGREEN adapters to forward 2 different thunderbolt video sources.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You've got to **read** what you link.  It says:

> For Mac computers with Apple silicon: You can connect a single external display to your Mac. Docks don’t increase the number of displays you can connect. On a Mac mini with an Apple M1 chip, you can connect a second display to the HDMI port. See the Apple Support article [Mac computers with Apple silicon](https://support.apple.com/HT211814).

There are solutions involving DisplayLink, which is running a monitor over USB, with the attendant performance degradation.

Comment: I am curious about one thing if I get an M1 MacBook in the future. Can I use 2 external monitors (not displaylink) if I put the MacBook into clamshell mode before docking? It’s still only 2 displays total at a time, because clamshell mode disables the internal monitor.

Comment: No, because the limitation isn't a count of monitors, it's the interface.